# How to read food labels?

Tags: nutrition

How are you supposed to read nutrition information on food labels? For example, how to determine whether the packaged food is healthy or not depending on the amount of sodium, protein, sugar, carbohydrates it has.

I have included two photos of similar cereals that I recently bought and I was wondering which one was healthier simply by reading the label?

[image: cereal 1] [image: cereal 2]

Comment: Hello Lschk. I've marked this question as a duplicate of [How do you read a US nutrition label?](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/283/26) If that question did not address what you are asking here, please edit this to show the differences. Thanks :)

Comment: @michaelpri It's a good answer, however I was wondering if anyone would be able to analyse the two cereals I uploaded.

Comment: I think it can be hard to say which is healthier. It all depends on what you are looking for in the cereal. For example, do you want a low-fat cereal? If so, go with the first one. The other question can help you determine that.

Comment: @michaelpri, Lschk - There are two questions. The first (how to read) is a duplicate. The second (Which is better nutritionally) is not. If you edited your question and explain what your nutritional goal is, the question could be possibly reopened and answered.